# SQL Left Outer Join and Right Outer Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm learning SQL and I was curious about type of JOINS. Does Table1 Left Outer Join Table2, Same as Table2 Right Outer Join Table1? Is there any difference at output due to the sequence?

Comment: Please spend a few minutes searching the site before you ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is difference.

[Check here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-left-right-and-full-outer-join/)

Left Outer Join returns all the rows from the table on the left and columns of the table on the right is null padded. Left Outer Join retrieves all the rows from both the tables that satisfy the join condition along with the unmatched rows of the left table.

Right Outer Join returns all the rows from the table on the right and columns of the table on the left is null padded. Right Outer Join retrieves all the rows from both the tables that satisfy the join condition along with the unmatched rows of the right table.

Comment: Asked and answered many times before.